# Why is Aptana/Pydev showing "undefined variable" errors for "print" and "__name__" in my helloworld python code?

Tags: python, aptana, pydev

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAe00.png

This is the first python program I made from scratch in Aptana. I literally copied this code from an exercise file. I set it to python 3.4 and grammar version 3.0. Why am I getting undefined variable errors for these most basic words?

Also, when I change the grammar and Interpreter both to version 2.7 the "print" error disappears but the **name** error still remains. Something is not right here.

```
def main():
    print("Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Edit: Also, if I simply open the .py file outside of the project these errors don't appear. So it seems something to do with project creation?

Comment: Copy the code and paste it in as a code block instead of linking to an image.

Comment: well its `_name_` defined?

Comment: I added the code block, but I know that's not the problem unless my Python course got their Hello World code wrong. The screenshot includes the various settings and project structure which I think is more valuable to anyone helping me troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug of Aptana:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8098

They say that it will be fixed in 3.6.2 version

Comment: Ah, thanks. That bug is 8 months old? If it takes that long to fix a pretty massive bug like that I think I'll switch to another IDE like Pycharm. It doesn't seem like they care about Python development.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that PyDev is not being able to connect to a shell to introspect your tokens... (in this case other things such as 'False' and 'True' would appear as invalid too).

Can you check if you have some error in your error log?

http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F has details on getting it...

If you do, please check if you have an active firewall which may be blocking things (if you still can't solve it, please create a new ticket at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/)

Comment: Thanks. I do have errors under true/false/etc. Here is more code http://i.imgur.com/fPCQP4f.png

Comment: I don't know why but there is no "PDE Runtime" in my Show Views>Other window. I checked your_workspace/.metadata/.log (I'm assuming workspace means the project folder?) and did not see any .metadata file (the only hidden files were .project, .pydevproject and .settings).

Comment: .metadata is a folder which is beneath your workspace folder (you have to go through the file explorer to see it)

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I'm seeing "!MESSAGE Port not bound (found port -1)" errors. I don't have any active firewall other than my airport extreme's default router settings.